# Dart: Prevent polymer transformer from changing my hrefs

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a polymer component with an HTML file which contains an anchor element `<a href="foo">`. This component is then imported with HTML import. The polymer transformer (or maybe the web_components transformer) will inline this import, and when doing so it will rewrite my anchor element to `<a href=/path/where/the/html/file/exists/foo">`.

Now I want to use the anchor tag to do client-side routing. I have a route set up as "foo" but when the transformer has rewritten the href that route will not work. So what I want is for the transformer to leave my href alone and just keep the original path. I tried using _href but that gives an error that it should only be used with bindings. So I guess my question is if there is any way to instruct the transformer to leave my hrefs alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```dart
<a _href="{{'foo'}}">
```

Comment: Binding to a constant, that was clever :-) I guess one-time binding to a constant would also work like href="[['foo']]". In the end I settled for href="#foo" and then in my client-side router I check for # and remove it.